# Is there a simpler way to write this code, recursively?

Tags: java

The goal for me is to write a method that takes 2 String array and sort the elements in the array by how long each element is. By Using Merge Sort???

This is the code that I have but I want it to be more condensed and I dont know if this code is recursive.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Test {

    private static Comparator<String> COMP = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            if(o1.length() < o2.length()) {
                return -1;
            }
            if(o1.length() > o2.length()) {
                return 1;
            }
            return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
        }
    };

    public static String[] mergeUnsorted(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
        arr1 = sort(arr1);
        arr2 = sort(arr2);

        return merge(arr1, arr2);
    }

    private static String[] sort(String[] arr) {
        if(arr.length <= 1)
            return arr;

        String[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, arr.length/2);
        String[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, arr.length/2, arr.length);

        left = sort(left);
        right = sort(right);

        String[] combined = merge(left, right);

        return combined;
    }

    private static String[] merge(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
        String[] combined = new String[arr1.length + arr2.length];

        int a = 0, b = 0, i = 0;

        while(a < arr1.length || b < arr2.length) {
            int compare = 0;
            if(a >= arr1.length) {
                compare = 1;
            } else if(b >= arr2.length) {
                compare = -1;
            } else {
                compare = COMP.compare(arr1[a], arr2[b]);
            }

            if(compare < 0) {
                combined[i] = arr1[a];
                i++;
                a++;
            } else if(compare > 0) {
                combined[i] = arr2[b];
                i++;
                b++;
            } else {
                combined[i] = arr1[a];
                i++;
                a++;
                combined[i] = arr2[b];
                i++;
                b++;
            }
        }

        return combined;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr1 = new String[] { "abc", "a", "A", "bA", "Ba" };
        String[] arr2 = new String[] { "def", "d", "D", "fG", "Fg", "abcde", "B" };

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mergeUnsorted(arr1, arr2)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the `sort` static method calls itself so, yes, it is recursive.

for what it does, and the language it does it in, and the efficiency achieved, it's not such bad code.  if you want shorter, why not use a Comparator and Arrays.sort?

(you could save a few lines in the ugly merge code by post-incrementing variables inside the array access)

Comment: Can you look at this code here and see if this might be better

Comment: Can you vote on this to be editied please so that I can change it please

Comment: no, not really, it's a pretty bad question.  sorry.